# when textview is selected, the button alters the text of the textview

Tags: android, button, textview

I want to create an app that stores 4 players lifetotal for a game. The 4 players start with 40 life and i have a button in the center that reduces the life of only the selected players by one. So how can i select 1 or 2 or 3 or all textviews and then press the button and alter their life?

Comment: you can use checkboxes instead of text views

Answer (score 0):

A view has the attribute 'selected'. You could set the status 'selected' on textviews. For example:

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```

Then for the button you can do something like this:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
if(textview.isSelected())
{
  //do something
}
//do the same for the other textviews

}
});
```

Maybe a more optimized method to do something like this is to use something like the hashmap and iterize its elements to check what textview is selected.